# C# linq union question

Tags: c#, linq, union

Could someone explain how does `Union` in LINQ work?

It is told that it merges two sequences and *removes duplicates.*

But can I somehow customize the duplicate removal behavior - let's say if I wish to use the element from `the second sequence` in case of duplicate or from `the first sequence`.

Or even if I wish to somehow combine those values in the resulting sequence?

*How should that be implemented?*

---

### Update

I guess I described the problem incorrectly, let's say we have some value:

```
class Value {
   String name
   Int whatever;
}
```

and the comparer used performs a `x.name == y.name` check.

And let's say that sometimes I know I should take the element from the second sequence, because it's `whatever` field is newer / better than the `whatever` field of the first sequence.

**Anyway, I would use the `sequence1.Union(sequence2)` or `sequence2.Union(sequence1)` variation of the methods.**

Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `second.Union(first)` instead of `first.Union(second)`. That way, it will keep the items from `second` rather than the items from `first`.

Answer (score 9):

> When the object returned by this method is enumerated, Union enumerates first and second in that order and yields each element that has not already been yielded.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx

So the elements from whichever sequence you use as the left parameter take precedence over the elements from right parameter.

The important thing about this is that it's well defined and documented behavior and not just an implementation detail that might change in the next version of .net.

As a side-note when you implement an `IEqualityComparer<T>` it's important to use consistent `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. And in this case I prefer to explicitly supply an equality comparer to the union method instead of having the `Equals` of the object itself return `true` for objects which are not identical for all purposes.

Comment: Thanks, this is the information that is required: specifically, the confidence that what could have been "mysterious black box behavior" is in fact documented and won't change without some fanfare--presumably, won't change at all.

Answer (score 5):

If the elements are duplicates then it doesn't matter which list they are taken from - unless your equality comparer doesn't take all properties of the element into account of course.

If they aren't really duplicates then they'll both appear in the resultant union.

**UPDATE**

From your new information at the minimum you should write a new equality operator that takes `whatever` into account. You can't just use `sequence1.Union(sequence2)` or `sequence2.Union(sequence1)` unless **all** the elements want taking from one sequence or the other.

At the extreme you'll have to write your own `Union` extension method which does this for you.

Comment: It depends on how you define equality... If the type implements `IEquatable<T>` (or the OP explicitly specified equality comparer), it's possible that the comparison doesn't take all members into account.

Comment: @Thomas - that was implied in my answer. Perhaps I should make it explicit.

Comment: @Thomas - my edit was prompted by your comment but within the 5 minute window ;)