# Outer Join in Linq or EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have two tables

```
T1     T2
-------------
id1    id2
-----------
1      3
2      5
3
4
```

I want to get a outer join so that I get 1,2,3,4,5

I am using following Linq command

```
   var newList = (from i in T1
                   join d in T2
                   on i.id1 equals d.id2 into output
                   from j in output.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   select new {i.id});
```

The out put I get i 1,2,3,4 missing 5. How can I get it to give me newList 1,2,3,4,5 
Help Please

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489987/linq-full-outer-join?rq=1

Comment: I already looked at it it has 2 columns on each table could not solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct alternative to `OUTER JOIN` in LINQ. You have to solve it like this:

Within query you wrote only the `i`'s that also exists in `T2` because of the `on i.id1 equals d.id2`.

```
var result = T1.Select(item => item.id1).Union(T2.Select(item => item.id2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Union like:

var result = T1.Union(T2);

You can refer to this [C# linq union question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419538/c-sharp-linq-union-question)